# Wrong Storage Space in El Capitan

Tags: macos, bootcamp, spotlight

I am running OS X EL Capitan (10.11.3) on my MBP and I have been trying to use BootCamp.  Whenever I try to open the *Boot Camp Assistant* it says you need at least 50 GB free space.  I have deleted many files (emptied the Trash) but the free space remains the same (43 GB).  I have read many solutions,  re-indexed Spotlight search couple of times, and restarted the machine several times.  But the free space is still the same. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your best bet is to delete apps that you don't use. Download applications like clean my Mac that really clean out the inner files hidden inside the file system, so that it opens up more data. Another option could be get an external harddrive and save everything to it, so that you can keep your Mac under 50gb

Comment: Come on. what happens to the files I deleted? :/

Comment: If you emptied the trash the memory is deleted from the hard drive

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many GBs is your hard drive, and is the 43GB part of the Windows partition or the Mac partition? Deleting files from the Mac partition won't free up any space on your Windows partition.

Comment: Well, I do not have a windows partition. TOtal size is 256GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## File Clearing

As user2277872 mentioned it's probably a good idea to get a disk analysis application to find out what's eating up your disk space. A few good applications to start with are DaisyDisk, OmniDiskSweeper and Disk Inventory X, each available [here](https://daisydiskapp.com/), [here](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) and [here](http://www.derlien.com) respectively.

If you find no big files cluttering up your space, here's another link covering some things that might be using up your disk space that you may have overlooked: http://www.howtogeek.com/184091/5-ways-to-free-up-disk-space-on-a-mac/

---

## Partition Resizing

However, if your 43 available GBs are **on your Windows partition**, no amount of file deletion on the Mac partition is going to help. What you need to do is resize the partitions.

*Disclaimer: it's always a good idea to make a backup. In theory, no data should get deleted but things can always go wrong. Grab an external HDD and image your system onto it, or at least copy your important files over.*

1. Boot into Recovery (`Cmd-R` on startup) and open Disk Utility.
2. Select your parent drive for both your Mac and Windows partitions (assuming they're on the same physical disk).
3. Click the Partition button in the toolbar and resize accordingly. You may want to allocate about 80GB to Windows or more depending on how much you intend to use it.
4. Click Apply and reboot. You should be able to boot into your Windows partition now.

Comment: I do not have a win. partition. I cant even pass the first step in bootcamp because it show the wrong disk space.

Comment: Have you tried Disk Utility's First Aid option? That might bring up an `Invalid Free Block Count` error. If not, try the section titled "File Clearing", that might help more

Comment: I used DaisyDisk and saw that 80GB space was taken for .MobileBackups then I disabled local backups and I got the space.

Comment: Were you able to enable Boot Camp after regaining this space? You can run `sudo tmutil disablelocal` to disable local snapshots.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should check your filled hard disk space using following third party application. With [Daisy Disk App](https://daisydiskapp.com/) you can easily identify the app space in your MBP hard drive.

Comment: The upvoted answer already mentions DaisyDisk.